# What does error "Type 'Any' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence" mean when I iterate through 'JSON' result?

Tags: json, swift

I am currently learning Swift. I am making an app that can parse historical data from a website and display these data in a chart view. I have been using `Alamofire` to parse `JSON` data from a webpage and trying to iterate through this results and try to store these data in an array. However, I have problems when I iterate through the `JSON` result. It says:

> "Type 'Any' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence".

This is the function I writes:

```
func getHistoryData(url: String) {
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
        print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url request
        print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
        print("Result: \(response.result)")                         // response serialization result

        if let json = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(json)") // serialized json response
            for item in json { ***(The error happens here)***

            }
        }

        if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("Data: \(utf8Text)") // original server data as UTF8 string
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a response sample from the webpages:

```
{
    "average": 4088.82,
    "time": "2019-03-30 15:46:00"
},
{
    "average": 4095.07,
    "time": "2019-03-30 15:45:00"
},
{
    "average": 4094.14,
    "time": "2019-03-30 15:44:00"
},
{
    "average": 4095.64,
    "time": "2019-03-30 15:43:00"
},
{
    "average": 4095.69,
    "time": "2019-03-30 15:42:00"
```

How can I get all the "average" and store them in an array?

Comment: Where is the code? I'd love to help you out, but you must have forgotten to paste it in :(

Comment: Hi, thank you! Some problems happened and I just uploaded the code. @NathanFiscaletti

Comment: If you share your JSON serialized data i can give you a bit better of an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what type of Sequence you're trying to get, but for the most part this should work.

Change

```
for item in json
```

to

```
var jsonparsed = JSON(json);
for item in jsonparsed.array
```

Based on your json, it would look something like this:

```
var averages : [Float] = [];

if let json = response.result.value {
    print("JSON: \(json)") // serialized json response
    var jsonparsed = JSON(json);
    for item in jsonparsed.array {
        if let average = item["average"].float {
            averages.append(average);
        }
    }
}

// do something with the `averages` array.
```

Comment: Thank you! I am new to the stack overflow community and just added part of the JSON response!

Comment: Shouldn't there be a "return" statement that return the "average" value and an empty array that appends those values?

Comment: Hello, I got an error on the jsonparse.array:Value of optional type '[JSON]?' must be unwrapped to a value of type '[JSON]', should I do what Xcode suggests? Coalesce using '??' to provide a default when the optional value contains 'nil' or Force-unwrap using '!' to abort execution if the optional value contains 'nil'

Comment: I did what the Xcode suggests and your solution actually works great for me :) Thank you so much!

Comment: generally, you would instead wrap it in `if let jsonparsed = JSON(json) { ...`

Comment: so I should change var jsonparsed = JSON(json) to if let jsonparsed = JSON(json) { ?

Comment: See here for an example of what i mean: https://gist.github.com/nathan-fiscaletti/8c3d8df47c501f0434e227b1f905909e

Comment: I would get the error at the second if statement: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'JSON'

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I've updated the gist: https://gist.github.com/nathan-fiscaletti/8c3d8df47c501f0434e227b1f905909e